# Thumbnails are not created?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am trying to create thumbnails original image is been uploaded to upload/large 
but not thumbnails are created in upload/thumbs I was using the CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class and it's not working.Help me to sort out problem

```
My Controller
          var $file_path;  //for original image
  var $file_path_url; //for thumbnails


 function __construct()
 {
      // Call the Model constructor
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('session');
      $this->is_login();
      $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
     $this->load->model('Edit_profile');
      //return full path of directory
      //Make sure these directory have read and write permission
      $this->file_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../upload/large');
      $this->file_path_url = realpath(APPPATH.'../upload/thumbs');

     // $this->load->model('Insert_article');        
 }

    function upload()
    {
        //loading image class
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('sessiondata');
        $user_id = $session_data['user_id'];
        //post image
        $img=$this->input->post("filename");
        //set preferences
        $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
        $config['upload_path'] = LARGEPATH;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size']    = '78000';

        //load moadel ********
        $this->load->model('Edit_profile');

        //load upload class library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        //$this->upload->do_upload('filename') will upload selected file to destiny folder
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            // case - failure
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $upload_error);
        }
        else
        {
            // case - success
            //callback  returns an array of data related to the uploaded file like the file name, path, size etc
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();


            // call to model function *********
            $data['images'] = $this->Edit_profile->insert_new_post($upload_data);

            //now creating thumbnails
            $config1 = array(
                    'source_image'      => $upload_data['full_path'],
                    'create_thumb'      =>true,
                    'overwrite'         =>false,
                    'maintain_ratio'    =>true,
                    'new_image'         => $this->file_path_url,
                    'maintain_ratio'    => true,
                    'width'             => 36,
                    'height'            => 36
                    );
                    print_r($config1);
                    $this->load->library('image_lib');
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($config1);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
            //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
            //$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            //$this->image_lib->resize();
            $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';



            redirect(base_url("Display_profilepic/index"));

        }  




    }

//Model
 function insert_new_post($upload_data)
    {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('sessiondata');
        $user_id = $session_data['user_id'];

        $filePath = ltrim(LARGEPATH.$upload_data['file_name'],'.');
        //print_r(LARGEPATH);
        $query = "UPDATE `tbl_usrs` set profile_picture='".$filePath."' where user_id='".$user_id."'";
       // $this->db->query($query,array($img));
       $arg=array ($upload_data);

        if($this->db->query($query,$arg)==true)
            {
                return true; // if added to database
            }else {
                    return false;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Is the image upload field called 'filename', as your code is expecting?

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara Array ( [source_image] => C:/xampp/htdocs/ko/upload/large/076a7b715ad34a10e8bc41b37d6c68ff.jpg [create_thumb] => 1 [overwrite] => [maintain_ratio] => 1 [new_image] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\upload\thumbs [width] => 36 [height] => 36 )  this is what print_r($config1);

Comment: @gabe3886 yup images are been uploaded to main folder but no thumbs are created in thumbs folder

Comment: @Optimmus did you have proper access to folder

Comment: that was my mistake, i already deleted that comment

Comment: what do you get if you run : `echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();`

Comment: in `$config1`, you should specify your library: `$config1['image_library'] = 'gd2'`; SOURCE: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=thumbnail#preferences

Comment: @CodeGodie Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.

Comment: @CodeGodie i have proper permission set for folder and is it necessary to lib i am not using gd2 lib

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi could you help me

Comment: @Optimmus  what is ouput of echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();

Comment: @CodeGodie can you help me...what i am missing

Comment: Firstly
Please update the new_image value by including the filename also.

$config['new_image'] = 'image/profile/' . $filename;
then show the print_r($config1); result

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi Array ( [image_library] => gd2 [source_image] => C:/xampp/htdocs/ko/upload/large/390e4d150aa84194c3daab69f7a05900.jpg [create_thumb] => 1 [overwrite] => [maintain_ratio] => 1 [new_image] => C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\upload\thumbs390e4d150aa84194c3daab69f7a05900.jpg [width] => 36 [height] => 36 )

Comment: @Optimmus bingo...... look at your result \upload\\**thumbs**390e4d150aa84194c3daab69f7a05900.jpg this what preventing you from writing the file

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi thnku so much i haven't seen that you can add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update the new_image value by including the filename also.

```
        $config1 = array(
                'image_library'=>'gd2',
                'source_image'      => $upload_data['full_path'],
                'create_thumb'      =>true,
                'overwrite'         =>false,
                'maintain_ratio'    =>true,
                'new_image'         => $this->file_path_url.'/'.$upload_data['file_name'], //add slash 
                'maintain_ratio'    => true,
                'width'             => 36,
                'height'            => 36
                );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the following code

```
$data = $this->upload->data(); $this->thumb($data);    
//Function for creating Thumbnails
        function thumb($data) {
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $data['full_path'];
            $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
            // $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config['width'] = 350;
            $config['height'] = 250;
            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            return true;
        }
```